# Printing 2D arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, printing

I have encountered a problem with printing 2D arrays. Here is my code, any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int NumRow, NumColumn;
int anArray[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
for (int N_column = 1; N_column < NumColumn; N_column++)
{
    for (int N_row = 1; N_row < NumRow; N_row++)
{
    cout << anArray[N_row,N_column];
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cout << anArray[N_row,N_column];` should be `cout <<anArray[N_row][N_column]` You also have no value for NumColumn and NumRow you need to set those to an integer value.

Comment: That [comma operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work) isn't doing what you think it is...

Comment: Before you try arrays of arrays (C++ doesn't have "2d" arrays), you might need to think about the term "*array of arrays*", and how that would be expressed in code. Then you would also understand why e.g. `anArray[N_row,N_column]` is wrong. And you also need to find a better understanding of simple arrays in general, and how they are indexed. I suggest you check out [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for a good beginner book or tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

3 problems:

1. Array indexes start at 0.
2. `NumColumn`, `NumRow` are uninitialized.
3. wrong syntax `[y,j]`, use `[i][j]`

Try like this:

```
...
int NumRow = 2, NumColumn = 2;
int anArray[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
for (int N_column = 0; N_column < NumColumn; N_column++)
{
    for (int N_row = 0; N_row < NumRow; N_row++)
    {
         cout << anArray[N_row][N_column];
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me to print out an answer, but one thing, why is it that I get: 1324 right next to each other instead of 1 2 and 3 4 under neath?

Comment: Not real problems but would improve the code nevertheless: 4. `NumRow` and `NumColumn` are not const. 5. `NumRow` and `NumColumn` are not used in the initialization of `anArray`. 6. `using namespace std;`

Comment: @Steven Did you print a line break in between? No. The compiler can't read your mind.

Comment: @Steven they are "connected" since you didn't print any separator (a space for example) and the order is "wrong" because you're iterating the outside array in the inside for and the inside arrayS in the outside for. switch the column / row variables in the `for`s to fix that

Comment: @zenith - very true, but hardly the right audience for that, don't you think? maybe after a few books :-)

Comment: @Amit Agreed, that's why it's only a comment :)

Answer (score 2):

You declare

```
int NumRow, NumColumn;
```

but you never assign a value to them. Use

```
int NumRow = 2, NumColumn = 2;
```

instead. Also, C-arrays [start at 0, not at 1](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/), so you must update your for-loops as well:

```
for (int N_column = 0; ...

    for (int N_row = 0; ...
```

Last, change the output statement, as multidimensional arrays need to be reached [in a different way](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/#multidimensional):

```
cout << anArray[N_row][N_column];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues in your code:

**1st:** You declare `NumRow, NumColumn` but use them without initializing them before which cause to [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Solution: Initialized them

```
NumRow = 2;
NumColumn = 2;
```

**2nd:** Array syntax in the following line-

```
cout << anArray[N_row,N_column];
```

it should be

```
cout << anArray[N_row][N_column];
```

**3rd:** C++ arrays are [zero indexed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), so you should start initializing the loop control variables like following:

```
for (int N_column = 0; N_column < NumColumn; N_column++)
{                   ^^^
    for (int N_row = 0; N_row < NumRow; N_row++)
    {               ^^^^
        //...
```